# The class 'FirebaseMessaging' doesn't have a default constructor I get this error after upgrading to Firebase massaging 10.0.4

Tags: flutter

> **Am getting the error on the FirebaseMessaging()**

```
class PushNotificationService
{
 final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
```

> **Am getting the error on the firebaseMessaging.configure**

```
 Future initialize(context) async
{
firebaseMessaging.configure(  
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
  },
);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code in question? In order to provide feedback, it would help to show what you are programming.

Comment: @pythonNovice  the quetion has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are initializing FirebaseMessaging like ‘FirebaseMessaging()’ when you should be initializing it by it’s instance as specified here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage.

So, in your case you would use
‘final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance’.

Feel free to check out my example in my GitHub repo here: https://github.com/dchicchon/Polus/blob/master/app/lib/main.dart

Comment: Hi pythonNovice i tried your suggestion and it seems it can work but i am new to flutter that's why I couldn't manage to tweak the code. i will appreciate if you can help me figure out where I can put this id which is coming from the database "retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context)" to replace it with the current upgrade. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Peter! What I would recommend is trying to work it out on your first through some trial and error/ googling first. If you still need help after that, I would just post another question on the forum if your code does not work as intended.